# Removing internal borders

Tags: python, opencv

I have a lot of cropped images from table image. `OCR` has some problems with text detecting because of "leftovers" of table borders. Actually i'm looking for way to remove them (I want to pick-up only text). Here are some examples of them:

[image: first image example]

[image: second image example]

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just cropping the images of _x_ pixels on each border (i.e. 5 pixels)?

Comment: Because there are some images that don't have that black borders, they are also very small sometimes and if I would crop them like you said, I would cut text too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Code (based on opencv) solves the problem for the two examples. The procedure is the following:

- threshold image
- remove lines from binary objects

  - compute ratio = (area of object)/(area of bounding box)

    - if the ratio is too small we consider the object to be a combination of lines
    - if the ratio is to big we consider the object to be a single line

here the python code:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread('om9gN.jpg',0)

# blur and apply otsu threshold
img = cv2.blur(img, (3,3))
_, img = cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# invert image
img = (img == 0).astype(np.uint8)


img_new = np.zeros_like(img)

# find contours
_,contours,_ = cv2.findContours(img, 1, 2)

for idx, cnt in enumerate(contours):

    # get area of contour
    temp = np.zeros_like(img)
    cv2.drawContours(temp, contours , idx, 1, -1)
    area_cnt = np.sum(temp)

    # get number of pixels of bounding box of contour
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    area_box = w * h

    # get ratio of cnt-area and box-area
    ratio = float(area_cnt) / area_box

    # only draw contour if:
    #    - 1.) ratio is not too big (line fills whole bounding box)
    #    - 2.) ratio is not too small (combination of lines fill very 
    #                                  small ratio of bounding box)
    if 0.9 > ratio > 0.2:
        cv2.drawContours(img_new, contours , idx, 1, -1)

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.imshow(img_new)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

[image: Isolated letters]

Comment: Great idea that should work in most cases. However it will also remove letters such as **l** (L), **I** (i), and **i** depending on the font used.

Comment: thats true. One option to avoid this could be to also put a threshold on the aspect ratio of the bounding box aspect-ratio (box_width / box_lenght). If the aspect ratio is too small it must be a line rather than an I, l, -, ...

Comment: and here I found an other way to remove lines from binary images: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/dee/tutorial_moprh_lines_detection.html

Comment: Thank you, nice idea! With some improvements it will work like I wanted!

Comment: above url has been changed to https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d1/dee/tutorial_moprh_lines_detection.html